# react-router Link and Route issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hear i pass link params to router

```
<Link to={'/brokerageListEdit/'+row.id} className="btn btn-warning">
   <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
</Link>
```

Hear i receive that params in router

```
<Route path='brokerageListEdit/:id' component={requireAuth(BrokerageListEdit)}/>
```

**When i click on Link i recived this error 
bundle.js:3274 Warning: [react-router] Location "/brokerageListEdit/7" did not match any routes**

**react-router version - 2.5.0**

Comment: please write your whole <Router>...</Router> configuration.

Comment: Yo it's working...Thanks @EmadEmami

Comment: ok, so do me a favor and set my answer as the right answer

Comment: @EmadEmami <Router path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home}/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write your whole configuration like this:

```
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
      <Route path='brokerageListEdit/:id' component={requireAuth(BrokerageListEdit)}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

- Edited